# Postgres Nodejs: Row value not updating correctly

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I have this table in the db:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."feedback" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('feedback_id_seq'::regclass),
    "title" text NOT NULL,
    "description" text,
    "created_on" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "category" text NOT NULL,
    "assignee_nickname" text DEFAULT 'unassigned'::text,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

The this setup on the server:

```
const updateAssign = (req, res) => {
    const assignee = req.body.assignee
    const feedbackId = req.params.id
    pool.query('UPDATE feedback SET assignee_nickname = $1 WHERE id = $2 RETURNING *', [assignee, feedbackId], (err, result) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.status(200).send(result.rows)
    })
}

Routes.put('/feedback/:id', updateAssign);
```

And finally sending this `PUT` request on Postman

to: `http://localhost:5000/feedback/10`

raw body:

```
{
    "assignee": "anna"
}
```

It returns the assignee_nickname as `null` instead of `anna`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 10,
        "title": "Ability to use %, em, ch, vw or similar units for dimensions.",
        "description": "The title is pretty self explanatory. Very rarely (if ever) the size of components is nowadays explicitly expressed in pixels (or points), but rather it depends on the context (CSS equivalents of %, vw, vh, for example) or content (ch). It would be great if we could express units in such ways (using 1fr for stack is a nice step).\n",
        "created_on": "2022-08-01T20:30:21.898Z",
        "category": "features",
        "assignee_nickname": null
    }
]
```

But running this query via my SQL client returning the expected result:

`UPDATE feedback SET assignee_nickname = 'anna' WHERE id = 10`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do `console.log(assignee)` and you'll find out why. Have you parsed the body as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If its showing the correct response in your sql client then my guess is you variable `assignee_nickname = $1` isn't receiving the correct datatype `text` or `assignee` is `undefined`
you should follow the data and `console.log(assignee)` in your `updateAssign` callback function. Then post response here.

Comment: weird thing about it is that I decided to ignore the failed Postman test and plugged it into the front-end app. It worked magically